# How to implement custom user-based authorization in jax-rs rest service?

Tags: java, rest, authorization, jax-rs

This [tutorial](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/26/jax-rs-resteasy-basic-authentication-and-authorization-tutorial/) explains how to do role authorization using jax-rs.

I am looking for user level authorization.  For example, for certain methods, such as removing or editing or accessing personal user information, only the user that is owner of that information should be able to access those resources.  What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: I personally use a CDI Interceptor for that.

Comment: Could you add some detail on this in an answer? That would be a valid answer that I would accept.

Comment: Not an answer, only a comment.  Your question's too broad.  Here's an article on using shiro w/ interceptors to do it http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-integrate-apache-shiro-with.html?spref=tw#.VPBr3lPF_qE

Answer (score 0):

Use XACML and a JAX-RS policy enforcement point in front of your JAX-RS service.

XACML is the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language. What XACML helps you achieve is:

- attribute-based access control where an attribute is just a key-value pair. An attribute could be the user id, the resource owner, the time of the day, the action...
- externalized authorization: decouple the business logic inside your JAX-RS service from the authorization logic now expressed in a central point called the policy decision point (PDP)
- policy-based: the authorization logic is expressed inside the PDP as policies that use the attributes previously defined. For instance:

  - *A user with the role==editor can do the action==edit on a document if the document.owner==user.id*

You can read more on XACML and ABAC here:

- ABAC: [NIST project page](http://csrc.nist.gov/projects/abac/).
- [XACML introduction & architecture](http://developers.axiomatics.com/blog/index/entry/xacml-reference-architecture.html).

You will need to deploy an interceptor (policy enforcement point) in front of the JAX-RS service you want to protect.